# Create Numbers 1-6 in random order using AWK

Tags: awk, random

I'm using AWK to generate values between 1 - 6 which need to come out in random order.  I have managed to sort out the logic for the creation of the right range of numbers but am struggling with reading those in to an array to prevent duplicate numbers being output.  Currently my code has this;-

```
BEGIN{
FS=""
}{
for (i=1; i<=6; ++i) {
v=(int (rand()*6)+1   
print v }
```

This currently outputs six numbers but shows duplicates 2, 2, 6, 1, 4, 2.
What I need the output to be is something like 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 3

Can anyone please help with the array side of this for my AWK program?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange.com, JonathanB. Have a quick look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 11):

Why use `awk` when, on most Unix boxes at least, you can just do:

```
$ seq 6 | shuf
5
2
3
4
1
6
```

or as @StéphaneChazelas mentioned in a comment `shuf -i 1-6`.

If you do want to use awk though then here's one approach using a [Knuth Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function shuf(arr,      i, j, n, tmp) {
    n = length(arr)
    for (i=n; i>1; i--) {
        j = int( 1 + rand()*i )
        tmp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[j]
        arr[j] = tmp
    }
}

BEGIN {
    srand()
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) { arr[i] = i }
    shuf(arr)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) { print arr[i] }
}
```

```
$ awk -v n=6 -f tst.awk
3
1
5
4
6
2
```

which just populates an array with the values you want, then swaps the value stored at every index in the array with a value stored at some other randomly selected index, then prints the array.

Note that the `shuf()` function above works in a single pass of the array.

Comment: See also `shuf -i 1-6`

Answer (score 4):

It seems as if you just want to *shuffle* the numbers between 1 and 6.

Most implementations of `sort` has an `-R` option to sort "randomly" (this option is not standard).  Most shells have "brace expansions" to generate combinations of strings, or numbers in ranges (brace expansions are not standard):

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..6} | sort -R
6
2
3
4
5
1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 720 (= 6! (6 factorial) = 1 × 2 × 3 × 4 × 5 × 6)
different ways of arranging six distinct things
(including the numbers 1 through 6). 
So one approach is to generate a random number between 1 and 6!
(well, actually, between 0 and 6!−1)
and map that to the corresponding permutation.

```
BEGIN {
        n = 6
        srand()
        # Compute n! (n factorial) and create an array of numbers.
        f = 1
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                f *= i;
                nums[i] = i;
        }
        # Get random number between 0 and n!-1.
        r = int(rand()*f)
        # Deconstruct it.
        for (i = n; i > 0; i--) {
                remainder = r % i + 1
                print nums[remainder]
                # Remove it from the array.
                for (j = remainder; j < n; j++) nums[j] = nums[j+1]
                r = int(r/i)
        }
}
```

This doesn’t scale well.

- My version of awk was able to compute 22! but it failed to compute 23!
- The algorithm is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>). 
  That means that, if it handled large values of *n*, 
  *n*=6000 would take a million times as long as *n*=6.

Advantages:

- You might want to use the above in a hypothetical world
  where `rand()` is very expensive, because it calls `rand()` only once.
- This algorithm makes it easy
  to produce the same sequence number of numbers repeatedly
  (by setting `r` to a known value rather than a random one).